# Sound not playing AudioToolbox Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to play an alarm sound, but when I've implemented the code, it runs, but no sound is played. What is the problem?

Here is my code (the important bits):

```
import UIKit
//Timer Sound
let timerSoundURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("alarm", withExtension: "caf")
var timerSoundID: SystemSoundID = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    //Setup sound for timer
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(timerSoundURL, &timerSoundID)
}

//Plays sound
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(timerSoundID);
    NSLog("Play sound")
}
```

Comment: Where does `timerSound` in `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(timerSound)` come from?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I changed the name of timerSound to timerSoundID. I've updated it to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, but you are probably testing it in the Simulator. If so, that's your mistake. `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound` doesn't work in the Simulator.

Run your code on an actual device and all will be well (except that you've got a memory leak, but that's another matter entirely - the point is, you'll hear the sound, if the resource is valid, when you run on the device).

Comment: I tried, but it still did not make any sound, even with my volume turned up fully. What is the memory leak you mentioned?

Comment: It isn't relevant, so let's not talk about it now; it doesn't affect the code. - So I would have to guess that either _alarm.caf_ isn't there or it isn't a valid sound file for this purpose. If you like, download this working example: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch14p640systemSound/ch27p910systemSound/ViewController.swift Maybe you can figure out why mine works and yours doesn't (even though they are almost identical).

Comment: The chief difference in our code, by the way, is that you have broken up the routine into four different pieces (two properties, `viewDidLoad`, and `viewDidAppear`, whereas my code just does all four things in one function. Perhaps you should try it my way. There's no harm in doing it my way, especially after you take care of the memory leak. :)